# Make non-operator version of symbol \equiv

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

In my thesis, I am using the `\equiv` symbol as a variable in several places. For this use, the operator spacing is actually unwanted. What is a good way of defining a second command giving the same symbol, but without the operator spacing?

My current best guess is to manually use `\hspace`, but that seems inelegant and seems to cause issues with alignment when using `align` environments.

Comment: You could enclose `\equiv` in braces. Compare  `a\equiv b` with  `a{\equiv}b`.

Comment: Really you want to reduce the space before and after for equiv symbol or you are looking for Triple bond?

Comment: It's hard to imagine `\equiv` as a variable name. Might it be a Greek letter `\Xi` instead?

Comment: I really wanted to use \equiv, am using it in the context of Myhill-Nerode equivalences, and am using the dual nature as an equivalence relation and subset of QxQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the `\ordequiv` command, as an ordinary math sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\ordequiv{\mathord{\equiv}}
\begin{document}
$a\ordequiv b$

$a\equiv b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just use brackets around the `\equiv` symbol, like this: `$a{\equiv}b$.`